# Does the available inventory in Sirta Supplies fluctuate?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I discovered a Sirta Supplies terminal at Huerta Medical Center. It's stocked full of various knicknacks like medi-gel capacity upgrades, flowers, candy, books, etc. Nothing too exciting. I'm looking for something more interesting when it comes to medical supplies.

**Does the Sirta Supplies terminal ever change its inventory?**

*(If not, I may have to take my medical supply needs to another terminal)*

[image]
*(Credit to [IGN.com](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Sirta_Supplies) for the image.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gift-type items will disappear once your Virmire Survivor makes it out of the hospital, leaving only the medi-gel capcity increase upgrades.

Sirta only offers that one item, normally, though not all ranks are available from the very beginning. (Not sure what causes the next upgrade to appear).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has medi-gel capacity upgrades until you've maxed them out.

Answer (score 0):

It is the terminal where you will find the upgrades to Medi-Gel, other than that I have been told the other items will slowly disappear, I bought everything first time there and nothing except for new Medi-Gel is available there.